# limit of an absolute sequence: ${b_n} = |{a_n} - 1|$

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {a_n} = 3  \cr 
  & {b_n} = |{a_n} - 1| \cr} $$

Hence,

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {b_n} = |3 - 1| = 2$$

Is it right to say that?
If so, is it sufficent for a proof?

Comment: do you mind write is an answer?

Comment: Yes. It's fine.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking, then it isn't sufficient. Consider this $$\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}a_n=3\implies \lim \limits _{n\to \infty}(a_n)-1=2\implies \left|\lim \limits _{n\to \infty}(a_n-1)\right|=2\mathop{\implies}^{\text{Why?}} \lim \limits _{n\to \infty}\left|(a_n-1)\right|=2.$$